# It's possible to rotate an object in gnuplot?

Tags: object, rotation, gnuplot, rectangles

I'm using software that uses Gnuplot language to plot some data, but I've never used Gnuplot before.

So I was trying to place labels and rectangles in a way that created a nice and readable text, which wasn't bad (as you can see with the number 182 in the image below), but I wanted to learn how to rotate the rectangle and label so that they line up with the white line.

(I can't post images, but it's like that in [this link](https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/secure.notion-static.com/8fd75937-e94c-4c32-92c0-5f5d2d16cabb/Untitled.png?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAT73L2G45EIPT3X45%2F20220203%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220203T181931Z&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Signature=75aea4b2fda6f439409925f30524be0203a0407fb25b48f318c561609c76ad95&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&response-content-disposition=filename%20%3D%22Untitled.png%22&x-id=GetObject) Right now, it looks like:

[image: Example])

I've already learned to rotate the label (as you can see the number 171), but apparently, it doesn't work the same way with the object.

```
# setting the label and rotating it works
set label 1 "TEXT" at 10, 20 center rotate by 30 front
# setting the object works
set object 1 rect center 10,20 size 1,2 front
# But this doesn't work
set object 1 rect center 10,20 size 1,2 rotate by 30 front
# this line return the error message "Unrecognized or duplicate option"
```

The important part of my code that sets a rectangle and a label is here below:

```
x1 = 2979
x2 = 3140
y1 = -225
y2 = -168
ang = 19.9275
h = 30
w = 60
# set object 1 rect center (x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2 size w,h rotate by ang front fillcolor "black" fillstyle transparent solid 0.5 noborder
set object 1 rect center (x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2 size w,h front fillcolor "black" fillstyle transparent solid 0.5 noborder
set label 1 sprintf("{/:Bold %1.0f}",sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)) at (x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2 center rotate by ang front tc rgb "white"
set arrow from x1,y1 to x2,y2 heads size 10,90 front linecolor rgb "white" linewidth 2.5 dashtype 6
```

So how do I rotate the rect object? And if it's not possible, is there another way to do this (other than having to manually set a polygon)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following example and `help labels`.
You can create a datablock and add your labels and plot them rotated and boxed together with your map.

**Edit:** ...forgot the semitransparent boxes. You need to play with the alpha channel, i.e. `0xAARRGGBB`.

**Code:**

```
### boxed semitransparent text labels
reset session

# create some background test data
f(x,y)=(sin(1.3*x)*cos(.9*y)+cos(.8*x)*sin(1.9*y)+cos(y*.2*x))*3+15
set samples 51
set isosamples 51
set table $Data
    splot [0:600][0:600] f(x/60.,y/60.)
unset table

$myLabels <<EOD
# text x   y   a
171    300   300   45
182    100   500   90
197    500   400   60
333    400   100  -30
EOD

set style fill transparent solid 1.0 noborder
set style textbox opaque fc rgb 0xaaffffff noborder
set angle degrees
set key noautotitle

plot $Data u 1:2:3 with image palette,\
     $myLabels u 2:3:1:4 w labels rotate var boxed font ",24"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: You were faster than me :-)
Anyway, the OP asked for transparent boxes, but I can't find a terminal that supports `transparent` instead of `opaque`; neither qt, cairolatex nor pngcairo gave correct results for me. Did you have any luck?

Comment: @Eldrad thanks for the hint. I missed the semi-transparent point. But, yes, you can do it. I will modify my answer.

Comment: your way worked just fine, but then I tried to do just the `set style textbox ...` and put the `boxed` in the end of the line `set label ...` , it works in the same way. Thank you for the insight!!!